# how to put condition check each group by value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here how my tables look like: 
CREATE TABLE my_table(id INT,emp_id INT,dept_id INT,salary INT,isapproved INT,isvalid INT); 
INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES 
  (1, e1, d1, 100, 1, 1),
  (2, e1, d2, 200, 0, 1),
  (3, e1, d1, 300, 0, 0),
  (4, e2, d1, 400, 1, 0),
  (5, e3, d2, 500, 1, 1),
  (6, e3, d1, 600, 1, 1),
  (7, e3, d1, 700, 1, 1),
  (8, e4, d3, 800, 1, 1);

what i want
first of all,i need to check the query group by emp_id , 
 i got **e1,e2,e3,e4** 
 then check each emp_id with condition **isapproved = 1 and isvalid = 1** 
 finally i want this answer
 **emp_id** 
 e3 
 e4 
note:
 i need single query.
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self join onto the table then exclude any which have a matching record which isn't approved or isn't valid.

```
SELECT mt.emp_id
FROM my_table mt
LEFT JOIN my_table mtx ON (mtx.emp_id = mt.emp_id AND (mtx.isapproved = 0 OR mtx.isvalid = 0))
WHERE mt.isapproved = 1 AND mt.isvalid = 1 AND mtx.id IS NULL
GROUP BY mt.emp_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94e248/2) (note I changed the type of emp_id and dept_id as these were integers but had string values).